# The code SetReducedMultiplication for semigroups

Tags: semigroups, gap

Let $S$ be a finite semigroup like this:

```
gap> f:=FreeSemigroup("a","b");;  
     a:=f.1;;  b:=f.2;;  
     s:=f/[[a^5,a],[b^5,a^2*b],[b^3*a,a*b^5]];;
     el:=Elements(s);
```

and assume you want to find the useful set $eSe$ where `e` is indeed `el[31]` an idempotent of $S$. So you do:

```
gap> l:=DuplicateFreeList(el[31]*el*el[31]);;
```

to find `l` as smaller as it can be:

```
[ a^3*b*a*b*a^4*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b^2*a^3*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b*a^5*b*a*b, 
      a^3*b*a*b*a*b*a^3*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b^2*a^4*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b^3*a^3*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b*a^6*b*a*b, a*b*a*b*a^2*b*a^3*b*a*b,   a^3*b*a*b*a*b*a^4*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b*a*b^2*a^3*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b^3*a^4*b*a*b,  a^3*b*a*b*a^7*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b*a^3*b*a^3*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b*a^2*b*a^4*b*a*b, 
     a^3*b*a*b*a^2*b^2*a^3*b*a*b, a^3*b*a*b*a^3*b*a^4*b*a*b ]
```

It seems annoying finding something like`a^3*b*a*b*a*b*a^4*b*a*b`. 
 Unfortunately the code `SetReducedMultiplication` didn’t work here and I just applied another code `Position`:

```
gap> List([1..16], i->Position(el,l[i]));
 [ 12, 25, 19, 4, 23, 20, 28, 8, 9, 10, 27, 31, 16, 17, 18, 26 ]
```

Is there an alternative code like `SetReducedMultiplication` for semigroups to reduce the lentgh of words or you suggest to use for example `Position`? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: This is a question about GAP, not about maths!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [KBMAG](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/kbmag.html) package:

```
gap> rws := KBMAGRewritingSystem(s);;
gap> MakeConfluent(rws);
true
gap> l := DuplicateFreeList(el[31] * el * el[31]);;
gap> List(l, x -> ReducedForm(rws, UnderlyingElement(x)));
[ b*a*b, a^4*b, (a*b)^2, a*b, b^2*a*b, a*b^2*a, a*(a*b)^2, a^2*b, a*b*a,
  a*b^2, a^3*b^2, a^2*(a*b)^2, a^3*b, a^2*b*a, a^2*b^2, a^3*b*a ]
```

`SetReducedMultiplication` does not work for finitely presented semigroups or monoids in GAP, and many of the methods in the GAP library for computing with finitely presented semigroups and monoids depend on a terrible implementation of the Knuth-Bendix algorithm in the GAP library. There are plans to improve this!

If you had a transformation representation of your semigroup:

```
gap> T := Range(IsomorphismTransformationSemigroup(s));
```

Then you can avoid these problems, although there is currently no method for calculating the local submonoid $eSe$ that you are interested in. If you file an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/james-d-mitchell/semigroups/issues?status=new&status=open) requesting this feature, we can add it in the next release of the [Semigroups](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/semigroups.php) package.